# Calculate means for multiple variables in with different sizes

Tags: r, data.table, mean

I have table and code is at below:

```
data <- data.frame(Subject = c(0,0,0,1,2,2),
                   Class = c("Apple","Apple","Apple","Orange","Orange","Orange"),
                   name = c(1,1,1,0,1,1),
                   name1 = c(0,1,1,1,1,1),
                   name2 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1))
```

I want to find the average of each variable for each class and each subject, and list it as a table. For example, the table will have average for subject first; 0 with mean 8/9 and 2 with mean 5/6. Second work out the mean for class; orange with mean 2/3. Finally breakdown the average for name,name1 and name2.

I have tried the code below, first store the header as a list and sort it by subject and class with lapply. But it isnt working.

```
cols = c(head(data))
data[,lapply(.SD[,cols,with=FALSE],mean),by=Class|Subject]
```

Comment: Maybe `setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = .(Class, Subject)]`? Reading up on `data.table` syntax might be a good idea. See the [*"Getting started"* wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: The col names are not in the head; use `names(data)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

data2 <- melt(data, c("Subject", "Class"))

data.frame(summarize(group_by(data2, Subject, Class),
                      avg_val = mean(value))) -> table_for_you
```

Comment: I think the table is what I am looking for, and I appreciated your quick reply. One more question, what if I have many variables, can I use mean(names(data)) to work out the average of every single variable? rather than list every single one.

Comment: data2 <- melt(data, names(data)[!names(data) %in% c("name", "name1", "name2")])

Comment: That will work for an unlimited number of variables, however you must list out the variables to exclude (i.e. name, name1, name2).

Comment: I think a more straight-forward dplyr solution would be `data %>% group_by(Subject,Class) %>% summarize_all(.,funs(mean))`